# Align columns in comma-separated file

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing the script in linux and the result of the script is a csv file. I want to format this file. My output file is:

```
"T_Hours","T_Count","T_Hours","P_Avg_5","Diffrence_Between_P_Avg_5_and_T_Count"
"00","446","00","533","87"
"01","159","01","224","65"
"02","95","02","140","45"
"03","84","03","117","33"
"04","92","04","113","21"
```

I want to make the output like this:

```
"T_Hours","T_Count","T_Hours","P_Avg_5","Diffrence_Between_P_Avg_5_and_T_Count"
"00"     ,"446"    ,"00"     ,"533"    ,"87"
"01"     ,"159"    ,"01"     ,"224"    ,"65"
"02"     ,"95"     ,"02"     ,"140"    ,"45"
"03"     ,"84"     ,"03"     ,"117"    ,"33"
"04"     ,"92"     ,"04"     ,"113"    ,"21"
```

What I try: I try to add spaces after the **,** and before it, but that doesn't work because the numbers do not always have the same width; for example, in the second column may be the number `"55556"` so adding a specific number of spaces will not work. So I think the solution is to shift the character `,` in all lines to put it under the `,` in the first line. Any help?

Comment: That's a crazy requirement. Keep your files in a standard computer-readable format.

Comment: FYI `Diffrence` should be spelled `Difference`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a portable way:

```
sed 's/,/:,/g' output.csv |
column -t -s: |
sed 's/ ,/,/g'
```

**Explanation:**

`column -t` aligns columns. The input separator can be specified with `-s` but the output separator is always a space (unless you have version like *GNU* or *util-linux* supporting the `-o` flag, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51478236/6770384).).

With `column -s, -t output.csv` the output would be just

```
"T_Hours" "T_Count" "T_Hours" ...
"00"      "446"     "00"      ...
"01"      "159"     "01"      ...
...
```

To keep the `,` in the output we have to pre- and post-process:

- Use `sed` to insert an additional delimiter `:` in front of each comma-delimiter. The character you choose has to be a character that isn't otherwise in your input.
- Use `column -t` specifying that `:` character as the delimiter. `column` will align all columns and replace all `:` by a space.
- Use `sed` to delete the spaces (originally the `:` we inserted in the first command).

```
"T_Hours","T_Count","T_Hours",...
"00"     ,"446"    ,"00"     ,...
"01"     ,"159"    ,"01"     ,...
...
```

More info, see `man column`.

Comment: When I run this against the supplied input, on my system, it introduces 2 extra spaces between each delimiter. To remove them is trivial: `sed 's/  ,/,/g' file`

Comment: There's no need for a UUOC and adding an extra character (`:`) that you hope won't be in the input and then removing the pre-`,` blanks afterwards. `column` can do everything just fine on it's own using just the existing `,` delimiter - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51478236/1745001.

Comment: @Socowi, no problem. If you can improve my answer with more on the "why" feel free. Note that, in 9 months, this post only had 291 views. Also, if you know more about which versions of column have a `-o` that's probably useful info. All I know is that I don't have a version with a `-o`!

Comment: This is a really good answer.  Issues will be faced when delimiters are embedded in quoted text and we need to ignore them? No switch/parm available yet.

Comment: This is not working when columns contain double quoted text having some commas.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ column -t -s, -o, file
"T_Hours","T_Count","T_Hours","P_Avg_5","Diffrence_Between_P_Avg_5_and_T_Count"
"00"     ,"446"    ,"00"     ,"533"    ,"87"
"01"     ,"159"    ,"01"     ,"224"    ,"65"
"02"     ,"95"     ,"02"     ,"140"    ,"45"
"03"     ,"84"     ,"03"     ,"117"    ,"33"
"04"     ,"92"     ,"04"     ,"113"    ,"21"
```

Comment: It should be noted however that many versions of column do not have the -o option, e.g. on the Mac OS X platform. (I considered rewriting without cat, and the result was horrible to read, which convinced me that UUoC does not apply here. :-) Good answer though.

Comment: Thanks. To remove `cat` from `cat file | sed 'script'` is `sed 'script' file`

Comment: Yes, I just thought it looked awful that way.

Comment: So `cat file` looks fine but `sed 'script' file` looks awful? Eye of the beholder I suppose...

Comment: Fair enough. I updated to show both, and importantly, to link to some UUoC wisdom. :-)

Comment: This is not working when columns contain double quoted text having some commas.

Comment: @swiss_knight it's not supposed to, see the question. It also wouldn't work if the quoted fields contained newlines but that's also not what this question is about.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1{p;s/[^,]/ /g;h;d};G;s/^/\n/;:a;ta;s/\n([^,])(.*\n)\s/\1\n\2/;ta;s/\n,(.*\n)([^,]*,)/\2\n\1/;ta;P;d' file
```

This uses the headers on the first line to set the column widths. Each data column is written over a space, comma separated template created from header.